# How to calculate pseudoinverse of a matix using JAMA (A Java Matrix Package)?

Tags: java, matrix, jama

I am trying to find inverse of a matrix. When it is singular I need to calculate pseudoinverse. I am not able to find anything like pseudoinverse in JAMA doc. How could I compute it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jama makes it for you

[documentation](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/doc/)

> ```
> public Matrix inverse()
>     Matrix inverse or pseudoinverse
>     Returns:
>         inverse(A) if A is square, pseudoinverse otherwise.
> ```